# Evaluate a function and assign to a constant to use as tick mark in Tikz/pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm defining some functions to plot using pgfplots and that has been successful. Now I would like to add a y tick at a point that's evaluated using these functions (lbound below). I can't seem to be able to use lbound as a constant however. This is to mark the point where the horizontal plot hits the y-axis. What should I do instead?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={
        tmin = 0;
        tmax = 1;
        C(\x) = (\x)^2;
        Cinv(\x) = (\x)^(1/2);
        ell(\theta,\tau,\K) = 1 - Cinv( (- (\tau * \theta) / (tmax - tmin) + \K) );
        lbound = ell(1, 0.8, C(1) + 0.8 * tmin / (tmax - tmin));
  }
    ]

    \begin{axis}[
            ytick={0,1},
            yticklabels={$0$,$1$}
            ]
        \addplot[dashed, thick, domain=0:1]{ell(1, 0.8, C(1) + 0.8 * tmin / (tmax - tmin))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! <s>I do not understand what the issue is. I can set a `y` tick using your constant.</s> This issue seems to be related to the version number. (I did not know this when writing the the first version of my answer.) With version of 1.16 of pgfplots it works in a straightforward way.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={
        tmin = 0;
        tmax = 1;
        C(\x) = (\x)^2;
        Cinv(\x) = (\x)^(1/2);
        ell(\theta,\tau,\K) = 1 - Cinv( (- (\tau * \theta) / (tmax - tmin) + \K) );
        lbound = ell(1, 0.8, C(1) + 0.8 * tmin / (tmax - tmin));
  }
    ]

    \begin{axis}[
            ymin=-0.5,ymax=1.5,
            ytick={0,lbound,1},
            yticklabels={$0$,$\ell$,$1$}
            ]
        \addplot[dashed, thick, domain=0:1]{ell(1, 0.8, C(1) + 0.8 * tmin / (tmax - tmin))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This works irrespectively of whether or not I set `ymin` and `ymax`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={
        tmin = 0;
        tmax = 1;
        C(\x) = (\x)^2;
        Cinv(\x) = (\x)^(1/2);
        ell(\theta,\tau,\K) = 1 - Cinv( (- (\tau * \theta) / (tmax - tmin) + \K) );
        lbound = ell(1, 0.8, C(1) + 0.8 * tmin / (tmax - tmin));
  }
    ]

    \begin{axis}[
%           ymin=-0.5,ymax=1.5,
            ytick={0,lbound,1},
            yticklabels={$0$,$\ell$,$1$}
            ]
        \addplot[dashed, thick, domain=0:1]{ell(1, 0.8, C(1) + 0.8 * tmin / (tmax - tmin))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for checking, but somehow it doesn't work for me. It works without the middle tick (lbound) but not with it. Error message below (I only have pgfplots version 1.13, not 1.16):
Package pgfplots Warning: Axis range for axis y is approximately empty; enlarging it (it is [0.5527:0.5527]) on input line 22.


test.tex:22: Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input 'lbound' as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near 'lbound'..

Comment: @cinny Then this might simply mean that there was an issue in older versions of pgfplots that has been fixed by now. What prevents you from updating it?

Comment: I just did! It just took forever since I haven't updated in a while... and then the updates caused some other issues that I had to fix. But yes, it indeed works out. Strange! I would never have figured this out, so thank you. Do you mind adding a note to your answer and I can accept it? Also, an extra question: could I have defined my functions and constants globally to be used in multiple tikz pictures? Thanks!

Comment: @cinny Done. Of course I did not know which version you are using, and I do not keep track of what changes between versions. Sorry for the tone in my original answer. I also did not know what's going on, and just could not reproduce the issue. I'm glad to hear that it works now! (BTW I am using TeXLive, with which updates are a piece of cake. ;-)

Comment: Yes, it's impossible to know, so seeing a full working example was the only way to find out! I do have TeXLive but just never use it... Plus the Mactex distribution itself has to be updated every year, and mine was from 2016...